# HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this html code:

```
            <div class="input-group registration-date-time">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="Span2"><span class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                <input class="form-control" name="registration_date" id="Date2" type="date"/>


            </div>
```

I'd like to click on my span (with id Span2)and open the calendar.

Thank,

Comment: Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

you maybe noticed that your question is not well prepared. Please have a look at the help center or look at other questions from users.

BUT: To answer your question have a look at this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/wfs30nbp/

```
<div class="form-group my-calendar">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
    <input type="date" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.my-calendar {
  .input-group-btn {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .form-control {
    background: transparent;
    padding-left: 50px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px!important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px!important;

    &::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator{
      opacity: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 40px;
      height: 34px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

NOTICE: type="date" cannot be interpreted by every browser and should be used carefully: http://caniuse.com/#search=type%3D%22date%22